.upper .split .isalpha method not working in python function
I'm having issues with the .upper, .split, and .isalpha methods in my Python function. These methods are not working as expected. Normally, in Visual Studio Code, these methods are highlighted with a specific color when they are recognized correctly. However, this time they are not highlighted. Additionally, when I hover over these methods with my cursor, it shows "(function) upper: Any", which indicates a problem. How can I resolve this issue in VS Code?
def crypto(crypt_input):
    

    crypt_input = crypt_input.upper()

    if len(crypt_input) == 0:

        raise Exception("Missing Argument")

    individual_symbols = crypt_input.split(",")

    if not all(symbol.isalpha() for symbol in individual_symbols):

        raise Exception("Input must be Alphabetical")

    else:
        symbols = ",".join(individual_symbols) #Comes in handy in cases where we want to serach for than one Coin

        url = f"https://production.api.coindesk.com/v2/tb/price/ticker?assets={symbols}" # url saved


    while True:
        result = get(url) #http request made 

        if result.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception(f"Failed to retrieve data:{result.status_code}")
        
        json_data = result.json() #data from url then parsed into Json

        results = []

        if "data" in json_data and isinstance(json_data["data"] , dict): # makes sure key "data" is actually existant in Parsed JSOn api and is a dictionary
            for symbol in individual_symbols:
                symbol = symbol.upper()
                try:
                    coin_data = json_data["data"][symbol] #Value:"BTC "of Key:"data" in this case would be another key to a sub dictionary
                    
                    if coin_data is None:
                        print(f"No data available for symbol{symbol}")
                        continue
                    
                    if all(key in coin_data for key in ('iso' , 'name' , 'ohlc')) and "c" in coin_data['ohlc'] and "ts" in coin_data:
                        results.append({
                            'iso':coin_data['iso'],
                            'name':coin_data['name'],
                            'Current_price':coin_data['ohlc']['c'],
                            "Timestamp": str(coin_data['ts'])

                        })
                    else:
                        print(f"Missing expected keys in coin_data: {coin_data}")
                except IndexError as e:
                    print(f"keyerror acessing data for symbol {symbol}: {e}")
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            print("Invalid or missing 'data' key in JSON response")
        
        for result in results:
            print(jsonify(results))


Does the code actually encounter errors when you run it?  Or is the problem only in the Visual Studio syntax highlighting?

I would guess that your IDE simply has no way to know that crypt_input in this function is a string, and therefore cannot determine what methods it actually has, or what types they return.  A type hint on the function's parameter might fix this.

Python 3 has support for type hints, to help IDEs and linters know what you're expecting something to be. There's no built in enforcement, it's just a hint for external tools.
from typing import Any

def crypto(crypt_input: str) -> None:
    ...
    # you can also add type hints to variables
    results: list[dict[str, Any]] = []
    ...

This says that crypt_input should be a string and the function doesn't return anything. The variable hint says results should be a list of dictionary, each with a string key and anything for the value.
There are some libraries that provide runtime checking, but at a performance cost, like typeguard.
